# how to remember the selected radio button option in diango

Tags: python, html, django, frontend, backend

I asked this question previously and didn't get any help/solution. So I'm asking again.

I'm trying to make sure that even if the user refresh the page or goes back and comes back to that page, the radio button is still the same as what the user selects.

N.B: the value of the radio button is saved in sessions

```
<div class="col-md-1 ps-md-1">
        <input class="align-middle h-100" type="radio" name="deliveryOption"  id="{{option.id}}"
          value="{{option.id}}">
      </div>
```

Ajax

```
$('input[type=radio][name=deliveryOption]').on('change', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{% url "checkout:cart_update_delivery" %}',
    data: {
      deliveryoption: $(this).val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
      action: "post",
    },
    success: function (json) {
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = json.total;
      document.getElementById("delivery_price").innerHTML = json.delivery_price;
      
    },
    error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
  });
  
});
```

my view

```py
def cart_update_delivery(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        delivery_option = int(request.POST.get("deliveryoption"))
        delivery_type = DeliveryOptions.objects.get(id=delivery_option)
        updated_total_price = cart.cart_update_delivery(delivery_type.delivery_price)

    session = request.session
    if "purchase" not in request.session:
        session["purchase"] = {
            "delivery_id": delivery_type.id,
        }
    else:
        session["purchase"]["delivery_id"] = delivery_type.id
        session.modified = True

    response = JsonResponse({"total": updated_total_price, "delivery_price": delivery_type.delivery_price})
    return response
```

when I added a django templating if statement, it kinda work but the radio button is always remember on the last radio button when refreshed.

```
{% for option in deliveryoptions %}
            
            <input class="align-middle h-100" type="radio" {% if deliveryoption ==  %} checked=1 {% elif delivery_option == 2 %} checked="checked"{% endif %} autocomplete='on' name="deliveryOption" id="{{option.id}}"
          value="{{option.id}}">
         
        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: it may need to keep values in DataBase and use cookies to recognize user - and when you see the same user then you get data from database and send to template.

Comment: and if this doesn't work then first you could use `print()` (and `console.lgo()`) to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: you use `for` loop to create checkbox but it seems you use the same values `2` in all `if/else` but every checkbox should check different value - `option.id` - `{% if deliveryoption == option.id %} checked="checked"{% endif %}`